# check whether a user connected to the Internet or not?

Tags: pascal

How do you check whether a user is connected to the Internet or not?

Comment: I need a function that retrun a boolean that say whether user connected to internet or not ?

Comment: Pascal? That's a blast from the past :0)

Comment: As far as I know the most recent Delphi release is not yet two weeks old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define internet (e.g. sometimes only certain services are accessable, like when only HTTP traffic through a proxy is allowed).

In general, the only somewhat reliable solution is simply to try and check if the targeted service responds.

Answer (score 0):

What flavor of Pascal are you using?  You should have some Internet library available.  If you want to know if there's a connection available, the easiest way to do that is to see if you can connect to anything.  How exactly you do this depends on your internet library, but if I had to do this I'd simply try to ping google.com and see if it succeeds or not.